# Mongoid: Object.to_json - how to load children objects as well?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

Mongoid doesn't include children documents into JSON when I do Object.to_json. How can I do it? I tried this:

```
@realty = Realty.includes(:comments).find(params[:id])
...
respond_to do |format|
  format.json  { render json: @realty }
end
```

But comments still doesn't get included in JSON.

Comment: can you please try this `Reality.includes(:comments)` http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html

Comment: I just tried this: `Realty.includes(:comments).find(params[:id])` - no error now, but Comments still doesn't get included in JSON

Comment: Please do this `@realtiy.to_json` in console and put the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use :include in the to_json call

```
@realty = Realty.find(params[:id])
...
respond_to do |format|
  format.json  { render json: @realty.to_json(include: [:comments]) }
end
```

You can include any association in there.

You can also use any random method:

```
@foo.to_json(methods: [:some_arbitrary_method])
```

This works for a smaller/simple api but check out:
[JBuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder), which is part of the Rails 4 default gem inclusion, obviously you can use this with any Rails version
[ActiveModel Serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers)

Comment: @oyatek If it is a really small and simple project, use of `to_json` as pointed out in answer should be fine, otherwise you might want to look into [RABL](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) or [Jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder)

Comment: @cpuguy83 great, it works! now, can I limit array of included comments somehow? Something like `include: [:comments].limit(3)`

Comment: You would have to setup a special relation for this... or create a new method on your instances
`def comments_limited(limit=3)
    comments.limit(limit)
end` and then use the to_json(methods: [:comments_limited]) instead

Comment: Or use jbuilder since you may want to do more things.

Answer (score 0):

I am just working on something like this and I use:

```
gem "active_model_serializers"
```

https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers

http://railscasts.com/episodes/409-active-model-serializers

in my case `Project has_many :posts` and the json result would be:

`{"projects":[{"id":1,"title":"test project","description":"nice test project","slug":null,"posts":[{"id":1,"title":"new test post for test project","body":"Some content here and there","responses":[],"author":{"id":1,"email":"admin@mail.md"}}],"members":[]}]}`

```
class ProjectSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title, :description, :slug
  has_many :posts
  has_many :memberships, key: :members
end

class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title, :body, :responses
end
```